# gcc/g++: "No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, c++-faq

`g++` gives me errors of the form:

```
foo.cc:<line>:<column>: fatal error: <bar>: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

It is the same when compiling C-programs with `gcc`.

Why is that?

---

<sup>**Please note:** This question has been asked many times before, but each time it was specific to the askers situation. This question's purpose is **to have a question that others can be closed as duplicates of**, once and for all; a *FAQ*.</sup>

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Your compiler just tried to compile the file named `foo.cc`. Upon hitting line number `line`, the compiler finds:

```
#include "bar"
```

or

```
#include <bar>
```

The compiler then tries to find that file. For this, it uses a set of directories to look into, but within this set, there is no file `bar`. For an explanation of the difference between the versions of the include statement look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename).

### How to tell the compiler where to find it

`g++` has an option `-I`. It lets you add include search paths to the command line. Imagine that your file `bar` is in a folder named `frobnicate`, relative to `foo.cc` (assume you are compiling from the directory where `foo.cc` is located):

```
g++ -Ifrobnicate foo.cc
```

You can add more include-paths; each you give is relative to the current directory. Microsoft's compiler has a correlating option `/I` that works in the same way, or in Visual Studio, the folders can be set in the Property Pages of the Project, under Configuration Properties->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories.

Now imagine you have multiple version of `bar` in different folders, given:

---

```
// A/bar
#include<string>
std::string which() { return "A/bar"; }
```

---

```
// B/bar
#include<string>
std::string which() { return "B/bar"; }
```

---

```
// C/bar
#include<string>
std::string which() { return "C/bar"; }
```

---

```
// foo.cc
#include "bar"
#include <iostream>

int main () {
    std::cout << which() << std::endl;
}
```

---

The priority with `#include "bar"` is leftmost:

```
$ g++ -IA -IB -IC foo.cc
$ ./a.out
A/bar
```

As you see, when the compiler started looking through `A/`, `B/` and `C/`, it stopped at the first or leftmost hit.

This is true of both forms, `include <>` and `incude ""`.

### Difference between `#include <bar>` and `#include "bar"`

Usually, the `#include <xxx>` makes it look into system folders first, the `#include "xxx"` makes it look into the current or custom folders first.

E.g.:

Imagine you have the following files in your project folder:

```
list
main.cc
```

with `main.cc`:

```
#include "list"
....
```

For this, your compiler will `#include` the file `list` in your project folder, because it currently compiles `main.cc` and there is that file `list` in the current folder.

But with `main.cc`:

```
#include <list>
....
```

and then `g++ main.cc`, your compiler will look into the system folders first, and because `<list>` is a standard header, it will `#include` the file named `list` that comes with your C++ platform as part of the standard library.

This is all a bit simplified, but should give you the basic idea.

### Details on `<>`/`""`-priorities and `-I`

According to the [gcc-documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html), the priority for `include <>` is, on a "normal Unix system", as follows:

```
 /usr/local/include
 libdir/gcc/target/version/include
 /usr/target/include
 /usr/include
```

> For C++ programs, it will also look in /usr/include/c++/version, first. In the above, target is the canonical name of the system GCC was configured to compile code for; [...].

The documentation also states:

> You can add to this list with the -Idir command line option. All the directories named by -I are searched, in left-to-right order, **before the default directories**. The only exception is when dir is already searched by default. In this case, the option is ignored and the search order for system directories remains unchanged.

To continue our `#include<list> / #include"list"` example (same code):

```
g++ -I. main.cc
```

and

```
#include<list>
int main () { std::list<int> l; }
```

and indeed, the `-I.` prioritizes the folder `.` over the system includes and we get a compiler error.

Comment: Just want to make you notice that it's kinda weird that you refer to your compiler as "your compiler" since the question and the answer has the same author.

Comment: @Jeffrey: Maybe the author of the question intended to fit the general format here. Dunno, ask him.

Comment: This answer is wrong, `#include <>` looks in the dirs listed with `-I` before default system dirs

Comment: "_Imagine that your file bar is in a folder named frobnicate, relative to foo.cc_" the dirs given with `-I` are relative to the dir where you run gcc, not relative to the file being compiled. The difference is significant if you do `g++ -Ifrobnicate blah/foo.cc`

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Thanks for pointing those out, I changed the answer accordingly. Seems like I exercised the `-I`/`<>`-test wrongly.

Comment: Do the settings of your `PATH` environmental variable (on Linux systems) affect how the compiler searches for files at all?

Comment: when using `#include "bar"` the compiler will look in the current directory _first_, before searching any other paths. Where the compiler looks for `#include <bar>` is implementation defined (you mentioned the gcc implementation). Some implementations may search the current directory, but only `#include "bar"` is obligated to. Similarly, `#include "bar"` is not obligated to search all the compiler-defined directories that `#include <bar>` does. The best advice is to use `"bar"` for user headers and `<bar>` for system headers (what constitutes a system header may be project-dependent)

Answer (score 0):

Also, there apprears to be a compiler bug in that if you include the characters "struct" or "Struct" in your header filename, the compiler will throw the same "no such file or directory" error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30174997)

Answer (score -5):

this works for me, sudo apt-get install libx11-dev