# compiling multiple cpp files

Tags: c++, windows, g++, mingw, nppexec

I am writing c++ in notepad++ using nppexec plugin and compiling with minGW.

I have a folder structure of:

```
projckt/
- main.cpp
- head/
-- vtk.h
- src/
-- vtk/
--- vtkFile1.cpp
--- vtkFile2.cpp
```

How do I compile and link? For my "hello world" scripts I used:

```
npp_save
cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"
g++ $(FILE_NAME) -std=c++11 -o $(NAME_PART)
NPP_RUN $(NAME_PART)
```

This works fine, I want a solution where I don't have to add a new .cpp file to the command when I create one. I have tried:

```
npp_save
cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"
g++ *.cpp -std=c++11 -o $(NAME_PART)
NPP_RUN $(NAME_PART)
```

It seems that the `.cpp` files in the sub directories is not included. Is there a way similar to copying subtree folders in unix `cp -r`.

Comment: You might use dedicated IDE to handle cpp workspace.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [g++ compile source files existing in another directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639443/g-compile-source-files-existing-in-another-directory)

Comment: @Jarod42 I used Visual Studio 2017 but felt that I did to much in the back ground, I want to learn what happens in the background before I rely on a IDE

Comment: @AndreKampling How do I impliment this in notepad++ with nppexec on windows

Comment: @MaltheEisum: Using makefiles see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile) and [how to make a simple makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481269/how-to-make-a-simple-c-makefile).