# c/c++ - warning: sched_policy.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, c

Im trying to compile ps.c from android toolbox but i keep getting the same error

here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <string.h>

#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>

#include <pwd.h>

#include <sched_policy.h>

static char *nexttoksep(char **strp, char *sep)
{
char *p = strsep(strp,sep);
return (p == 0) ? "" : p;
}
static char *nexttok(char **strp)
{
return nexttoksep(strp, " ");
}

#define SHOW_PRIO 1
#define SHOW_TIME 2
#define SHOW_POLICY 4
#define SHOW_CPU 8
#define SHOW_MACLABEL 16

static int display_flags = 0;

static int ps_line(int pid, int tid, char *namefilter)
{
char statline[1024];
char cmdline[1024];
char macline[1024];
char user[32];
struct stat stats;
int fd, r;
char *ptr, *name, *state;
int ppid, tty;
unsigned wchan, rss, vss, eip;
unsigned utime, stime;
int prio, nice, rtprio, sched, psr;
struct passwd *pw;

sprintf(statline, "/proc/%d", pid);
stat(statline, &stats);

if(tid) {
    sprintf(statline, "/proc/%d/task/%d/stat", pid, tid);
    cmdline[0] = 0;
    snprintf(macline, sizeof(macline), "/proc/%d/task/%d/attr/current", pid, tid);
} else {
    sprintf(statline, "/proc/%d/stat", pid);
    sprintf(cmdline, "/proc/%d/cmdline", pid);
    snprintf(macline, sizeof(macline), "/proc/%d/attr/current", pid);
    fd = open(cmdline, O_RDONLY);
    if(fd == 0) {
        r = 0;
    } else {
        r = read(fd, cmdline, 1023);
        close(fd);
        if(r < 0) r = 0;
    }
    cmdline[r] = 0;
}

fd = open(statline, O_RDONLY);
if(fd == 0) return -1;
r = read(fd, statline, 1023);
close(fd);
if(r < 0) return -1;
statline[r] = 0;

ptr = statline;
nexttok(&ptr); // skip pid
ptr++; // skip "("

name = ptr;
ptr = strrchr(ptr, ')'); // Skip to *last* occurence of ')',
*ptr++ = '\0'; // and null-terminate name.

ptr++; // skip " "
state = nexttok(&ptr);
ppid = atoi(nexttok(&ptr));
nexttok(&ptr); // pgrp
nexttok(&ptr); // sid
tty = atoi(nexttok(&ptr));

nexttok(&ptr); // tpgid
nexttok(&ptr); // flags
nexttok(&ptr); // minflt
nexttok(&ptr); // cminflt
nexttok(&ptr); // majflt
nexttok(&ptr); // cmajflt
#if 1
utime = atoi(nexttok(&ptr));
stime = atoi(nexttok(&ptr));
#else
nexttok(&ptr); // utime
nexttok(&ptr); // stime
#endif
nexttok(&ptr); // cutime
nexttok(&ptr); // cstime
prio = atoi(nexttok(&ptr));
nice = atoi(nexttok(&ptr));
nexttok(&ptr); // threads
nexttok(&ptr); // itrealvalue
nexttok(&ptr); // starttime
vss = strtoul(nexttok(&ptr), 0, 10); // vsize
rss = strtoul(nexttok(&ptr), 0, 10); // rss
nexttok(&ptr); // rlim
nexttok(&ptr); // startcode
nexttok(&ptr); // endcode
nexttok(&ptr); // startstack
nexttok(&ptr); // kstkesp
eip = strtoul(nexttok(&ptr), 0, 10); // kstkeip
nexttok(&ptr); // signal
nexttok(&ptr); // blocked
nexttok(&ptr); // sigignore
nexttok(&ptr); // sigcatch
wchan = strtoul(nexttok(&ptr), 0, 10); // wchan
nexttok(&ptr); // nswap
nexttok(&ptr); // cnswap
nexttok(&ptr); // exit signal
psr = atoi(nexttok(&ptr)); // processor
rtprio = atoi(nexttok(&ptr)); // rt_priority
sched = atoi(nexttok(&ptr)); // scheduling policy

tty = atoi(nexttok(&ptr));

if(tid != 0) {
    ppid = pid;
    pid = tid;
}

pw = getpwuid(stats.st_uid);
if(pw == 0) {
    sprintf(user,"%d",(int)stats.st_uid);
} else {
    strcpy(user,pw->pw_name);
}

if(!namefilter || !strncmp(name, namefilter, strlen(namefilter))) {
    if (display_flags & SHOW_MACLABEL) {
        fd = open(macline, O_RDONLY);
        strcpy(macline, "-");
        if (fd >= 0) {
            r = read(fd, macline, sizeof(macline)-1);
            close(fd);
            if (r > 0)
                macline[r] = 0;
        }
        printf("%-30s %-9s %-5d %-5d %s\n", macline, user, pid, ppid, cmdline[0] ?    cmdline : name);
        return 0;
    }

    printf("%-9s %-5d %-5d %-6d %-5d", user, pid, ppid, vss / 1024, rss * 4);
    if (display_flags & SHOW_CPU)
        printf(" %-2d", psr);
    if (display_flags & SHOW_PRIO)
        printf(" %-5d %-5d %-5d %-5d", prio, nice, rtprio, sched);
    if (display_flags & SHOW_POLICY) {
        SchedPolicy p;
        if (get_sched_policy(pid, &p) < 0)
            printf(" un ");
        else
            printf(" %.2s ", get_sched_policy_name(p));
    }
    printf(" %08x %08x %s %s", wchan, eip, state, cmdline[0] ? cmdline : name);
    if(display_flags&SHOW_TIME)
        printf(" (u:%d, s:%d)", utime, stime);

    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}


void ps_threads(int pid, char *namefilter)
{
char tmp[128];
DIR *d;
struct dirent *de;

sprintf(tmp,"/proc/%d/task",pid);
d = opendir(tmp);
if(d == 0) return;

while((de = readdir(d)) != 0){
    if(isdigit(de->d_name[0])){
        int tid = atoi(de->d_name);
        if(tid == pid) continue;
        ps_line(pid, tid, namefilter);
    }
}
closedir(d);
}

int ps_main(int argc, char **argv)
{
DIR *d;
struct dirent *de;
char *namefilter = 0;
int pidfilter = 0;
int threads = 0;

d = opendir("/proc");
if(d == 0) return -1;

while(argc > 1){
    if(!strcmp(argv[1],"-t")) {
        threads = 1;
    } else if(!strcmp(argv[1],"-x")) {
        display_flags |= SHOW_TIME;
    } else if(!strcmp(argv[1], "-Z")) {
        display_flags |= SHOW_MACLABEL;
    } else if(!strcmp(argv[1],"-P")) {
        display_flags |= SHOW_POLICY;
    } else if(!strcmp(argv[1],"-p")) {
        display_flags |= SHOW_PRIO;
    } else if(!strcmp(argv[1],"-c")) {
        display_flags |= SHOW_CPU;
    } else if(isdigit(argv[1][0])){
        pidfilter = atoi(argv[1]);
    } else {
        namefilter = argv[1];
    }
    argc--;
    argv++;
}

if (display_flags & SHOW_MACLABEL) {
    printf("LABEL USER PID PPID NAME\n");
} else {
    printf("USER PID PPID VSIZE RSS %s%s %s WCHAN PC NAME\n",
           (display_flags&SHOW_CPU)?"CPU ":"",
           (display_flags&SHOW_PRIO)?"PRIO NICE RTPRI SCHED ":"",
           (display_flags&SHOW_POLICY)?"PCY " : "");
}
while((de = readdir(d)) != 0){
    if(isdigit(de->d_name[0])){
        int pid = atoi(de->d_name);
        if(!pidfilter || (pidfilter == pid)) {
            ps_line(pid, 0, namefilter);
            if(threads) ps_threads(pid, namefilter);
        }
    }
}
closedir(d);
return 0;
}
```

and sched_policy.h

```
#ifndef __CUTILS_SCHED_POLICY_H
#define __CUTILS_SCHED_POLICY_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

 typedef enum {
    SP_DEFAULT    = -1,
    SP_BACKGROUND = 0,
    SP_FOREGROUND = 1,
    SP_SYSTEM     = 2,  // can't be used with set_sched_policy()
    SP_AUDIO_APP  = 3,
    SP_AUDIO_SYS  = 4,
    SP_CNT,
    SP_MAX        = SP_CNT - 1,
    SP_SYSTEM_DEFAULT = SP_FOREGROUND,
} SchedPolicy;

extern int set_sched_policy(int tid, SchedPolicy policy);

extern int get_sched_policy(int tid, SchedPolicy *policy);

extern const char *get_sched_policy_name(SchedPolicy policy);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

I have 0 knowledge in c/c++, im trying to compile this with eclipse
Tried also with gcc from command line same error

I need it for my java project

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919081/gcc-g-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: It's C, not C++. And the *error* means that the file cannot be found. Consult Eclipses CDT docs for adding paths to directories which hold header files.

Comment: I never developed C with Eclipse, but the most likely explanation is that the header file is in a location where the compiler doesn't find it.

Comment: solved by changing `#include <sched_policy.h>` to `#include "sched_policy.h"` but now i get different error

Comment: now i get `undefined reference to 'main'` and `undefined reference to 'get_sched_policy'` and `undefined reference to 'get_sched_policy_name'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference in using include:
* `#include <some_library>` - this will search for the library file in the standard folders
vs
* `#include "some_library"` - this will search for the file within your current working directory.

You want to use `#include "sched_policy.h"`

Check out the answer to this question for more information on differences:
[What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include "filename"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)