# Error Installing Libffm: 'No such file or directory.'

Tags: python, makefile

I am presently trying to install the Python wrapper of libffm stored in [this](https://github.com/turi-code/python-libffm) Git repository. I cloned both the repositories as was suggested by the quick-start guide, but ran into the following error when running the 'make' command in terminal.

```
'fatal error: parallel/winpthreadsll.h: No such file or directory'
```

I attached a screenshot below for convenience. The funny thing is that when I check in the specified directory, 'winpthreadsll.h' does indeed exist. Thoughts on why this error occurs? Thanks!

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKKjn.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You reported it in [issue 10](https://github.com/turi-code/python-libffm/issues/10), but that was already reported in [issue 5](https://github.com/turi-code/python-libffm/issues/5).

See "[gcc/g++: “No such file or directory”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12919082/6309)", and see if you can indicate to the compiler where the parent folder of parallel/winpthreadsll.h is.

Comment: Thanks VonC! I was able to use -I to help the compiler locate the file.