# Can not find <torch/extension.h>

Tags: c++, pytorch

I create a pytorch extention, followed by [this link](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_extension.html#building-with-setuptools)
but it throws out the error that

> fatal error: torch/extension.h: No such file or directory.

```
ubuntu 18.04
code::blocks 17.04
gcc 7.4.0
```

```
#include <torch/extension.h>
```

I expect the code to run.
Is there any document to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you installed the necessary development libraries?

Comment: The compiler can't find the file. So either the file doesn't exist in the right folder (i.e. you didn't set up torch properly?) or you haven't updated your project's include directories. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919081/gcc-g-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: i find https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/installing.html  doc  to install c++ extention for pytorch @StephenNewell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is the canonical header file that create Python bindings for C++/Cuda extensions. 
So Try upgrading the version of Pytorch if it's not in newest version.